# XVesa automatic fallback resolution?

Tags: linux, xvesa

How can I configure XVesa (parameters, perhaps) to automatically fall back to a second or third resolution if the first fails? Is such a thing possible or would it have to be done from an external "monitor" application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Xvesa does not support fallback resolutions and it's hard to hack it in by monitoring the process as it will not realize (there not quit) if it's started with an incorrect resolution or frequency. The best solution I found was to parse and use the output of `--display-modes` which is surprisingly accurate given how poorly Xvesa's autodetection works (which makes me suspect a bug in the latest code, shame it's no longer developed).